# How to split a number into three sets

Tags: python

I have got an a number: like 5
i need to split it into 3 sets like

```
2
1 4

2
2 3

1
5
```

Or the number 8:

```
2
8 4

2
7 5

4
1 2 3 6
```

I try to

```
def partition(n):
    if n < 5:
        return
    s = n * (n + 1) // 2
    if s % 3 != 0:
        return
    s //= 3
    lst, result = [i for i in range(1, n + 1)], []
    for _ in range(2):
        subset, s_current = [], s
        while s_current > 0:
            idx_max = bisect_right(lst, s_current) - 1
            subset.append(lst[idx_max])
            s_current -= lst[idx_max]
            lst.pop(idx_max)
        result.append(subset)
    result.append(lst)
    return result
```

If it can't make 3 sets, should return -1
But it doesn't work what i want
please, help

Comment: Divide all natural numbers from 1 to n into three sets so that the sum of the numbers in each set is the same.

Comment: What part of your script doesn't work?  Do you get an error or just incorrect answer?  If you get incorrect answer is it for all values of n or just some values?  What have you done to debug your script?